# How can I graphically represent a vector in as a circle?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have an Array of multiple values which represent cars with their velocities. It looks something like this:

```
    Array={{car1,vel1,position1},{car2,vel2,position2},....}
```

These cars are all supposed to be on a circle road of length n. The n should be kept as a variable so I can change it later as desired, it only needs to statisfy the condition that `n=>Length[Array]` How can I visually represent this road, such that it is a circle and one can see the position of the cars and its corresponding velocities?

The circle should be segmented into n-many parts of equal arclength. So if i have a car at the position 7, then it should be at the 7th segment of the circle.
The vel value can be represented either as a number or as a vector pointing tangentially to the circle, or ideally wrapping around the circle.
All the values in the Array will be positive integers. Ofcourse the data can be represented differently then by an array.

Comment: Put a point at the position and an arrow at the position of length proportional to the speed, tangent to the circle.

Comment: But how is the `position` defined?  Arc length? Please make your question more specific. Also, notice `Array` is a function in _Mathematica_ so you cannot use it as a variable.

Comment: …Are you looking for `PieChart` or `SectorChart`?

Comment: @xzczd  I was hoping for something like in the image attached, but I think Sectorchart is more similiar. <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CXebkNj3l9U/hqdefault.jpg">

Comment: How will you represent the position where there's no car? Also, can you add some specific data to your question for us to play with?

Comment: @xzczd where there is a car the segment can be colored red and where there is no car the segment can be colored white for example. Also, the cars have different velocities so if You want to play around with it, its a cool idea to make the cars be different shades of red. `{{1, 4, 1}, {2, 9, 7}, {3, 13, 7}, {4, 18, 3}, {5, 26, 3}, {6, 27, 
  6}, {7, 28, 1}, {8, 38, 5}, {9, 39, 7}, {10, 43, 5}}` These are the data that im using for the cars.

Comment: What's the value of `n` here? Please add all these to the body of question to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 5):

As you did not post data, I create some arbitrary data:

```
n = 5;
pos = CirclePoints[5];
vel = RandomReal[0.2 {-1, 2}, {n, 2}];
vel = (RandomReal[0.4 {-1, 1}] {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}} . #) & /@ pos;
array = Transpose[{Range[n], vel, pos}];
```

Now with this data we can create the graphics:

```
Graphics[{Circle[], PointSize[0.02], Point[array[[All, 3]]], 
  Arrow[{#[[3]], #[[3]] + #[[2]]}] & /@ array}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]